# Unexpected NoSuchMethodError RowMetadata.getColumnMetadatas() - In spite of correct dependencies

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

When running my application (Spring Boot 2.5.7) - after updating to spring-data-r2dbc 1.3.7, I get the `NoSuchMethodError RowMetadata.getColumnMetadatas()`.

(I have also tried this with 1.4.0 - 1.3.7 is where the problem first surfaces.)

In this spring-data-r2dbc release, a change has been made to move off of `getColumnNames` (See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/683) to `getColumnMetaDatas()`.

What is odd is that I also have the dependencies

- r2dbc-spi - 0.9.0.RELEASE
- org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql - 0.9.0.RC1

The 0.9.0 RC1 of r2dbc-postgresql fulfills the spi contract. So, it seems that everything should be in place -

The correct version of spring-data-r2dbc (1.3.7) invokes `getColumnMetaDatas()`:

```
public static boolean containsColumn(RowMetadata metadata, String name) {

        for (ColumnMetadata columnMetadata : metadata.getColumnMetadatas()) {
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(columnMetadata.getName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

which is a method of the 0.0.9.RELEASE r2dbc-spi interface `RowMetaData`, which is fulfilled by the 0.9.0.RC1 version of r2dbc-postgresql `PostgresqlRowMetadata`.

I have looked at my maven dependency tree and see no competing versions of any of these.

I could assume that the binding of the implementation to the spi is bad, but I got far enough to make the call to the database and then try to extract the data, so that doesn't seem right.  So, it appears that something else is off.

I added the command line option `-verbose:class` to see what classes/jars are being loaded and things look correct from there as well:

```
[30.756s][info][class,load] io.r2dbc.postgresql.message.frontend.CompositeFrontendMessage$$Lambda$2382/0x0000000800ee3840 source: io.r2dbc.postgresql.message.frontend.CompositeFrontendMessage
[30.756s][info][class,load] io.r2dbc.postgresql.message.frontend.Bind$$Lambda$2383/0x0000000800ee3c40 source: io.r2dbc.postgresql.message.frontend.Bind
[30.757s][info][class,load] io.r2dbc.postgresql.message.frontend.Bind$$Lambda$2384/0x0000000800ee4040 source: io.r2dbc.postgresql.message.frontend.Bind
[30.757s][info][class,load] io.r2dbc.postgresql.message.frontend.Bind$$Lambda$2385/0x0000000800ee4440 source: io.r2dbc.postgresql.message.frontend.Bind
[30.761s][info][class,load] io.r2dbc.postgresql.message.backend.ParseComplete source: file:/<removed>/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/r2dbc-postgresql/0.9.0.RC1/r2dbc-postgresql-0.9.0.RC1.jar
[30.762s][info][class,load] org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.RowMetadataUtils source: file:/<removed>/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-r2dbc/1.3.7/spring-data-r2dbc-1.3.7.jar
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
io.r2dbc.spi.RowMetadata.getColumnMetadatas()Ljava/lang/Iterable;
  at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.RowMetadataUtils.containsColumn(RowMetadataUtils.java:38)
  at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.extractGeneratedIdentifier(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:646)
... 2 frames excluded
  at io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlResult.lambda$map$2(PostgresqlResult.java:123)
  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(...
```

I've also

1. Updated my JDK to the latest version of Corretto 1.8
2. Compiled spring-data-r2dbc 1.4.0 with that version and used it
3. Inserted code in RowMetaDataUtils to reflect and log the methods found in the `metadata` parameter of `containsColumn(...)`.  The results include `public java.util.List<io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlColumnMetadata> io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlRowMetadata.getColumnMetadatas()`, which makes this even more perplexing.

I'll try and get a test that duplicates this - but hope that somebody has an idea for me to try to fix or debug with.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally had time to come back to this.  Looking at the byte code for `RowMetadataUtils`, we see

```
public static boolean containsColumn(io.r2dbc.spi.RowMetadata, java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Lio/r2dbc/spi/RowMetadata;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    flags: (0x0009) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=4, args_size=2
         0: aload_0
         1: invokeinterface #2,  1            // InterfaceMethod io/r2dbc/spi/RowMetadata.getColumnMetadatas:()Ljava/lang/Iterable;
         6: invokeinterface #3,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/lang/Iterable.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
        11: astore_2
```

In this we see that we are looking for an interface method `RowMetadata.getColumnMetadatas` that returns an iterator.
This is the signature of the 0.8.5 release of r2dbc-spi.  In later versions, this has been changed to return a list which would be resolved to the appropriate method in r2dbc-postgresql.  So, the 1.4.0 release of spring-data-r2dbc should be compiled against the 0.0.9.RELEASE version of r2dbc-spi.

Comment: Resolved by reflectively invoking `RowMetadata.getColumnMetadatas`:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/699